# Remove local changes done on file added by git add

Tags: git

I have one file called test.c in my git repo.

Now i have performed some **delat1** changes on test.c and performed git add command. and now git status -s gives as below output.

```
git add test.c
git status -s
M  test.c
```

Now i have again performed **delat2** changes on top of (test.c + delat1) and now git status -s shows as below

```
git status -s
MM  test.c
```

(First M is green and 2nd M is displayed in red font in vim)

Now i want to remove my **delta2** changes. and want to go back at **test.c + delat1** changes level

How to do that?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your second set of changes and keep the first set, correct?  If so, the answer is easy: `git checkout test.c`.  It will checkout the file from the staging area and put that data into your working tree.  IOW, it will overwrite test.c with whatever is in the staging area. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your run `git status`, you will see your local files ("delta2"), your staged files ("delta1").

**As `git status` tells you**, to get rid of your local changes ("delta2"), you can run:

```
git checkout test.c
```

The file will then be at the state of "delta1"

Comment: I am not too sure when `git status -s` comes in handy, it seems to be the same output as `--porcelain`, which is used for scripts; but with colors, making it very hard to use in script but keeping it hard to read for humans. But maybe it is just a matter of habit to be fair, which is fine :-)